# Are there past examples of China commiting to and then managing to boost its imports by dozens of billions of dollars?

Tags: economy, china, trade, history

In the recently [announced](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-51114425) US-China [mini]deal

> China has pledged to boost US imports by $200bn above 2017 levels and strengthen intellectual property rules.

I'm curious how realistic is the first part of such a promise in historical perspective, despite the state-control aspects of the Chinese economy. Basically, what is the largest such past commitment [to boost imports] that China made and that they actually managed to uphold?

Comment: I first suspected that at least a large part of that increase would happen through regular growth of US/Chinese trade but some quick googling showed that US exports to China have been between 110 and 130 billion dollars per year since at least 2012 with no clear trend and 2017 is the high point. So 200 billion more than 2017 would be an enormous increase relative to recent trade.